# Spring MVC No mapping found for HTTP request with URI in DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

I write site, and i have to use html page. When I write with jsp page I get good result, but I don't use HTML page because I get error:

> INFO: Server startup in 4792 ms
>
> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TestSpringMVC/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'
>
> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TestSpringMVC/index.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'

This is my welcome html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <a href="home">click</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my home.html page:

```
<body>
  <h1>this is home page</h1>
</body>
```

This is my **web.xml**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
   <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
  </listener>

   <servlet>
     <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
     </servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

**HelloWeb-servlet.xml:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="main.test.spring" />
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/page/html/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
</bean>
```

My controller:

```
    @Controller
    public class HelloController{
       @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String printHellow() {
          return "page/html/home";
       }
    }
```

p.s. I use Tomcat 7

Comment: First try from browser `http://localhost:8080/TestSpringMVC/home` and see if it hits the controller.

Comment: when i go to `http://localhost:8080/TestSpringMVC/home` I have
`HTTP Status 404 description The requested resource is not available.`

Comment: Your tomcat server is running on port 8080 only ri8? Next change `return "page/html/home";` to `return "home"`;

Answer (score 0):

```
 <url-pattern>/*.html</url-pattern>

 to add different type you need to add the type such as above code, and if you  
 were to add json then /*json should be added as well .Hope that solves your 
 problem
```

Comment: if I add /*.html I have error
`SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TestSpringMVC]]`

Comment: in your WEB-INF folder are are keeping your view File as .html or ,jsp ?

Comment: the error is rather generic isn't it? have you tried InternalResourceViewResolver instead of UrlBaseViewResolver?

Comment: in my WEB-INF i have .html files.
No I have not tried InternalResourceViewResolver

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet.xml has this:  `<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/page/html/"/>`

and you are returning `"page/html/home"` in your controller, so essentially that's the same as `page/html/page/html/home`.

You simply want to `return "home"`

Also you need a mapping for your webroot e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home() {

    return "home";
}
```

Comment: I changed my code and received result
`WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TestSpringMVC/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'`

Comment: Why the TestSpringMVC?  What happens when you try to access /HelloWeb/ ?

Comment: i have page with error 404

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of items you need to do. 
1. Your `HelloWeb-servlet.xml` is missing `<mvc:annotation-driven />`. This is required for registering handler mapping and handler adapter.

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
     xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="main.test.spring" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/page/html/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    </bean>`
```

2. Your view resolution needs to be corrected in the controller. Since you have defined `/WEB-INF/page/html/` in your view resolver, you don't need that in your controller.

```
@Controller
    public class HelloController{
       @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String printHellow() {
          return "home";
       }
    }
```

Assuming your tomcat listens at port 8080 and web context is TestSpringMVC, here is the URL you can try.

```
http://localhost:8080/TestSpringMVC/home
```